# Developing a machine-learned interatomic potential for molecular dynamics

Tags: molecular-dynamics, lammps, machine-learning, interatomic-potentials, intermolecular-forces

There are few questions in this SE about the advantages/disadvantages of machine-learned interatomic potentials in molecular dynamics, but there is not much discussion on how to make them. I thought it might a good question to ask:

**How to construct a machine-learned interatomic potential for a system of our interest?** (e.g., I am interested in studying deep eutectic solvents involving acetamide and lithium perchlorate).

Comment: +1, but what do you think of this: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9145/5? Also for others, I'd like to list the "few questions" to which you alluded in your opening sentence: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8737/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2172/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/181/5

Comment: I gotta say, this is a very, very large question. It is possible to give a very general answer that will cover it, but such a general answer is unlikely to be useful. Is there any way you could break it down to smaller chunks?

Comment: I'm particularly interested in tools available to construct such ML learnt potentials and what softwares are enabled to use them

Comment: @AndreyPoletayev Perhaps the user could ask "What software is available to help construct interatomic potentials using ML?" with the [tag:software-recommendations] tag? I think it would have to be asked in a new question, since changes to the question at this point would make things unfair for the people who have already written answers, like Prof. Camps in this case).

Comment: This is a related question / answer: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6212/4515

Answer (score 3):

I think this paper can help you:

Quantum neural networks force fields generation
Oriel Kiss, Francesco Tacchino, Sofia Vallecorsa and Ivano Tavernelli
Mach. Learn.: Sci. Technol. 3 035004 (2022)
DOI: [10.1088/2632-2153/ac7d3c](https://doi.org/10.1088/2632-2153/ac7d3c)

Abstract:

> Accurate molecular force fields are of paramount importance for the efficient implementation of molecular dynamics techniques at large scales. In the last decade, machine learning (ML) methods have demonstrated impressive performances in predicting accurate values for energy and forces when trained on finite size ensembles generated with ab initio techniques. At the same time, quantum computers have recently started to offer new viable computational paradigms to tackle such problems. On the one hand, quantum algorithms may notably be used to extend the reach of electronic structure calculations. On the other hand, quantum ML is also emerging as an alternative and promising path to quantum advantage. Here we follow this second route and establish a direct connection between classical and quantum solutions for learning neural network (NN) potentials. To this end, we design a quantum NN architecture and apply it successfully to different molecules of growing complexity. The quantum models exhibit larger effective dimension with respect to classical counterparts and can reach competitive performances, thus pointing towards potential quantum advantages in natural science applications via quantum ML.

Comment: Interesting paper title! [I published a paper 7 years ago](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4943622) with "quantum neural networks" in the title, far before it become such a popular term. It was still selected as an "Editor's pick" and for the journal cover too though :)